# Autodesk Forge Viewer3d search using attributeNames

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to implement .search() and restrict attributeNames using the optional parameter but it always brings back an empty array.

https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/

Can someone clarify how this filter is being applied?  I was expecting it to look at the returned property.displayName but apparently that's not the case.

Example:

```
viewer.search('13-097', function (ids) {
   console.log(ids);

   var id = ids[0];
   viewer.getProperties(id, function (obj) {
      console.log(obj.properties);
   });
}, function (e) { });

viewer.search('13-097', function (ids) {
   console.log(ids);
}, function (e) { }, ['ADDRESS']);
```

Output:
first search:

```
[8095]
```

second search:

```
[]
```

from object 8095, properties:

```
10:Object
displayCategory:"DWF - Construction"
displayName:"ADDRESS"
displayValue:"13-097"
hidden:false
type:20
units:null
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note the [Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D.search()](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/) method is NOT case sensitive on the **text** parameter, but it IS case sensitive on the **attributeNames** parameter, and you need to use the full name of the attribute.

If you are using the **displayName** of properties to correlate, note that **viewer.getProperties()** is currently returning the **displayName**. When there is no displayName, then (and only then) attribute name is returned.

Below is a sample I tried before (adjusted to your dataset):

```
function search() {
    viewer.clearSelection(); // remove previously highlighted searches

    var searchStr = '13-097';     
    var searchPropList = new Array('ADDRESS');
    viewer.search(searchStr, searchCallback, searchErrorCallback, searchPropList);
}

function searchCallback(ids) {
    alert(ids.length);
}

function searchErrorCallback(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

**EDIT (Oct 24, 2016)**

The [Viewer 2.11](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/changelog/2.11/) .getProperties method returns attributes, which can be used on the .search attributesNames parameter.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work or I'm just not clear on how/if I can use a search this way.  I added an example to my first post.

Comment: @JOfford please check the answer again, added a code sample.

Comment: Using your code I got the same thing:  1 found when you exclude "searchPropList" and 0 when you include it.

Comment: thanks for testing, let me investigate a little more. What's the Viewer version you are using?

Comment: Same as the forge viewer tutorial.  https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-viewer/